How to build 32/64-bit binary in older macOS?
I need to build an open-source VST universal binary i386 + x86_64 but I have "The i386 architecture is deprecated. You should update your ARCHS build setting to remove the i386 architecture." error in Xcode. I installed macOS X SDK 10.13 and currently that folders' content:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs:
MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX10.13.sdk
MacOSX10.13.sdk

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs:
MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX10.13.sdk
MacOSX10.13.sdk -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk

In Project's Build Setting Architectures are set to x86_64 i386, Base SDK is set to macosx10.13 and Supported Platforms to macOS. I've been able to build this before but I don't remember how. What should I do to compile it?
I tried flipping suggested settings but I'm surprised to see that message, I had MacOSX10.14.sdk, which probably not allows for compiling i386 but I moved it to a different place.
